# Autohotkey and chrome ahk open each chrome windows and run a click even

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I have a webpage that I am trying to click a link and it will make the site full screen. I already hit the f11 button but there is another click event that i have to hit. I am using autohotkey and it is not working

I was able to look at the button code and right click and copy JS path

```
document.querySelector('#een-fullscreen > i').click();
```

I added the click part and when i run it in the console it did full screen the site. I just can not get it in code. I modified code as below . It still does not see the windows and full screen. I am not sure what I am missing at this point.

```
#Include C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Chrome.ahk

f1::
WinGet, list, List, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
Loop %list% {
    hwnd := list%A_Index%   ; handles are in variables list1, list2, list3 etc. up to list%list%
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
    Loop, 12 { ; max number of tabs
        WinGetTitle, WLName, ahk_id %hwnd% ;
        if(InStr(WLName, "Eagle Eye Networks")>0){
        
        page.Evaluate("document.querySelector('#een-fullscreen > i').click()")

            }
    Send ^{Tab}
    Sleep, 5
    }
}
```